# Kofax validation rules

Tags: kofax

I'm trying to update a form which requires fields to be validated. 
My issue is that the required field can be "fileNumber" or "corporateNumber". For this I use validation rule and create a validation rule on multifield.

My issue is to know how i can create a relation within those two fields. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a multi-field validation rule in that case. Kofax Transformation Modules includes one for invoices (named Invoice Validation); everything else has to be written from scratch (Multi-Field Script Validation, in Project Settings > Validation).

In your case, check if the `.Text` property of either validation object, and then set `Valid` accordingly. Here's an example:

```
If Len(pField1.Text) = 0 AndAlso Len(pField2.Text) = 0 Then
    ValidField = False
    ErrDescription = "Either A or B is required!"
End If
```